# php var inside javascript inside php

Tags: javascript, php

so I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work. what im trying to do is

```
<?php
  $php_var = a-thing;
  echo '
  <script text/JavaScript>
    document.cookie = "arrayid"+'.$php_var.'+;
  </script>
';
?>
```

so when im not trying to set the array placement '.$php_var.' through just fine. can someone please help me with what I would assume is a syntax error on my part, please

Comment: why not just set the cookie from php?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: I want to place it in [id][var] but i can only call the php var when placing in [var] in the array but i dont know/havent found the proper syntax. also thanks for not roasting on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. (php) You have an erroneous semi-colon `;` after `$php_var`
2. (js) You need double quotes around the javascript string (if `$php_var` is a string)
3. (html) You are missing the `type=` attribute name in the script tag (you are using the default value for the attribute so you could just use `<script>...</script>` instead)

```php
<?php
  $php_var = a-thing;
  echo '
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.cookie = "arrayid"+"'.$php_var.'";
  </script>
';
?>
```

Comment: my bad on the ; I accidentally added it while jotting my question. also its a int I forgot to mention sorry and But thank you very much. I got your answer to work using the int method. I used a useless "+"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$aThing=7;
$php_var = $aThing;
echo '<script>document.cookie ="arrayid'.$php_var.'";</script>';?>
```

There is not much to explain. The PHP script generates the following string:

```
<script>document.cookie ="arrayid7";</script>
```

I left out the `text/JavaScript` part, as HTML5 does not require this anymore.

See the little demo here: https://rextester.com/HSCMD53489

Comment: Please try again - fixed it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `<?=$php_var;?>` this will echo the variable in normal html code.

```
<?php
  $php_var = "a-thing";
?>
  <script text/JavaScript>
    document.cookie = "arrayid"+<?=$php_var;?>;
  </script>
```